# Bind query result to datatablde

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable

Sample in C# or VB.NET are welcome.

I want to bind the following query result to datatable:

```
Dim query = From c in db.Customers _
            Where c.Status = "Active" _
            Select c.CId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Email
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a datagrid / datagridview by any chance? Cant quite get why you would want to bind to a datatable..

Comment: Do you mean that you want to store the result of this query in a DataTable?

Comment: I have a function which returns DataTable. I want to store query result in DataTable, so I can use it with UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim dtCustomer = New DataTable("Customer")
        dtCustomer.Columns.Add("CId", GetType(Integer))
        dtCustomer.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(String))
        dtCustomer.Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(String))
        dtCustomer.Columns.Add("Email", GetType(String))

        For Each q In query
            dtCustomer.Rows.Add(New Object() {q.CId, q.FirstName, q.LastName, q.Email})
        Next
```

Check out [DataTable class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)